# Build API for support pagination and non-paginate on Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

As I work on Django-rest-framework. I want the API to support dynamic pagination.

For example, if user need pagination they can use an endpoint `/api_url?offset=0&limit=10`(should return with the format that can let the user know the current page and have the next page or not) and if they don't want pagination they just request without params `/api_url`. I need it to work with `django_filters` so it won't make many requests to SQL.

I expect to get solition or sample code to about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the default Pagination class and override the get_page_size class like this:

```
class YourPaginationClass(PageNumberPagination):
    def get_page_size(self, request):
        if not request.GET.get("limit") and not request.GET.get("offset"):
            return None
        return super().get_page_size(request)
```

If you return None it will not paginate the queryset and return it in full.